# Repeating part of texture over another texture

Tags: glsl

So I'm trying to replace a part of a texture over another in GLSL, first step in a grand scheme.
So I have a image, 2048x2048, with 3 textures on the top left, each 512x512.  For testing purposes I'm trying to just repeatedly draw the first one.

```
//get coord of smaller texture
coord = vec2(int(gl_TexCoord[0].s)%512,int(gl_TexCoord[0].t)%512);

//grab color from it and return it 
fragment = texture2D(textures, coord);
gl_FragColor = fragment;
```

It seems that it only grabs the same pixel, I get one color from the texture returned to me.  Everything ends up grey. Anyone know what's off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless that's a rectangle texture (which is isn't since you're using `texture2D`), your texture coordinates are *normalized*. That means that the range [0, 1] maps to the entire range of the texture. 0.5 always means halfway, whether for a 256 sized texture or a 8192 one.

Therefore, you need to stop passing non-normalized texture coordinates (texel values). Pass normalized texture coordinates and adjust those.

Comment: Yes, I believe not realizing gl_TexCoord[0] is 0-1 was my main problem.  Does that mean I can unnormalize it, and then renormalize it?  I tried amtCoord = vec2(((int(gl_TexCoord[0].s)*2048)%512)/2048,((int(gl_TexCoord[0].t)*2048)%512)/2048);  But still didn't work.

Comment: @jfbguy: That's because you keep converting them to *integers*. Dividing an integer that is less than 2048 by 2048 will always yield *zero*. Or, you could just not unnormalize them: `texture2D(textures, gl_TexCoord[0].st / 2.0)`.

Comment: Whoops :).  I keep forgetting to add .0f at the end.  I agree, it would be nice to keep everything normalized but I couldn't think of a way to use modulus without integers, since with my big texture, I needed to keep everything between 0 to .25f,  thus the reason I was modulating 512 using a texture of size 2048. I did get it working though changing the 2048 to 2048.0f.

Comment: @jfbguy: You don't need to use modulus. Just divide the texture coordinate by 4.0 instead of 2.0 the way I did. Indeed, you should probably do that in the *vertex* shader.